# Use stylized action bar in every activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, material-design

I wanted to use a custom color and font and size for my app's name in the action bar, so I went in and stylized it in MainActivity.java like so

```
    //stylize the action bar
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setText(R.string.Title);
    tv.setTextSize(45);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "KGALittleSwag.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(tv);
    updateOptionsMenu();
```

This did the trick, and then when I added another activity I copied this code into it, and it looked great.  At this point my app is almost ready to release, but I'm doing some refactoring and I now have 6 or so activities, and it feels more than a little redundant to put this code in each of them.  Is there a better practice for applying these changes to the action bar universally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) is for.

Create an `abstract BaseActivity` Class, in which you'll fo all these processing. All your activities where you want to apply these styles will inherit for `BaseActivity`.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

         //stylize the action bar
         TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
         tv.setText(R.string.Title);
         tv.setTextSize(45);
         tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
         Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "KGALittleSwag.ttf");
         tv.setTypeface(tf);

         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
         getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(tv);
         updateOptionsMenu();

    }
}
```

Then your children activities:

```
public abstract class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState); // Here it calls the parent onCreate method and therefore executes the styling code
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like a good way to go for me, thank you!  One question though, do I create the BaseActivity class in my folders alongside all my other classes or is there another way to make it abstract?

Comment: @PaxanaNonGrata you can create just a regular Java class on the root of your `activities` package (assuming you have one). You'll treat it like any Java class, the only difference is that it's going to be abstract and won't have an XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just make a `XML` layout file for your custom action bar, and than use that in all activities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="your text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

make sure that your `TextView` is centered, and that `layout_width` and `layout_hight` for your `TextView` is set to `wrap_content`

Than put this into every activity that you want to use custom action bar

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```